# HTML/PHP Get the content of a .txt file user-side with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, html

I am trying to print on the page the content of a `.txt` file that the user would have uploaded beforehand.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<form action="page.php" method="POST">
    <input type="file" name="userfile"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Load"/>
</form>
```

On page.php :

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents($_POST['userfile']);
?>
```

The error I get:

> "Warning: file_get_contents(userfile.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

It does work when the `.txt` file is in the same directory as the `page.php`.

But the files that will be printed won't be in this directory, on the server.

How can I do that?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `$_POST['userfile']['tmp_name']`

Comment: Take a look yourself what is contained inside `$_POST['userfile']`. Since the uploaded file has not (yet) been saved on the server side (at least not in the local directory why you are looking for it), how should the script fetch it's content? Please take a look at the official documentation about how to handle uploaded files in the server side.

Comment: Oh so I should save the file on server before ? I'll try that. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use enctype="multipart/form-data" in form

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In PHP

```
echo file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer ! But I get an error "Warning: Illegal string offset 'tmp_name' ".

Comment: check in both place you used ``userfile`` as name and you must upload file or else it shows this error